# using background-image with php

Tags: php, html, css, image

I retrieve an image from the database with php
and then I want to use this image in `html` as a background.

I try to use this code, but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?php echo "<img src='getImg.php?id=$13'>"; ?>');"></div>
```

Comment: variable `$13`? From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), *A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rajdeep Paul is correct the variable is invalid also

your syntax for the css is incorrect:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?php echo "getImg.php?id=$X13" ?>')"></div>
```

no `<img src` ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `background-image:url` **syntax** and `variable` **name** are **incorrect**, try the folowing:

```
<?php
echo "<div class='fill' style=\"background-image:url('getImg.php?id=$VALIDVARIABLE')\"></div>";
```

---

**Rules for PHP variables:**

1. A variable starts with the `$` sign, followed by the name of the
   variable
2. A variable name **must start with a letter or the underscore character**
3. A variable name **cannot start with a number**
4. A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and
   underscores (`A-z`, `0-9`, and `_` )
5. Variable names are **case-sensitive** (`$age` and `$AGE` are two **different**
   variables)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $url = require("path/to/getImg.php?id=".$13;); ?>
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $url; ?>');"></div>
```

I am not sure about this line:

```
<?php $url = require("path/to/getImg.php?id=".$13;); ?>
```

But the value what you need to use on the background-image:url('anything') is not a img tag... sure. You need to put the url to the image.

I hope it helps you.